# Laravel - route 404 not found - how fix it?

Tags: php, laravel, api, http-status-code-404, cpanel

I am creating a mobile application(flutter) that works with api on Laravel. The api should work but there are problems. I'm trying to figure it out, although I don't have previous experience with Laravel (I have experience with PHP). so on server Cpanel. when i try to call the api i get an error

```
 404 Not Found
```

body:

```
 The requested URL was not found on this server.
 Additionally, a 404 Not Found
 error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request
```

This is a fairly common problem, the points I checked are the following points.

1. the api is in the public_html folder, some folders inside:

   ```
   app

   routes

   bootstrap
   ```
2. checked file public_html/.htaccess

   ```
    # php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
    # Set the “ea-php74” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
    <IfModule mime_module>
      AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php74 .php .php7 .phtml
    </IfModule>
    # php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
   ```

I changed it to:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
 </IfModule>
```

4. executed the following commands

   ```
    php artisan route:clear

    php artisan route:cache
   ```

after that i execute the command

```
    php artisan route:list
```

result:

[image]

I try the following options for the url:

```
  https://appdomain.com/api/v1/login
  https://appdomain.com/api/v1/Check-login
  https://appdomain.com/api/v1/user-login  
  https://appdomain.com/api/login
  https://appdomain.com/api/Check-login
  https://appdomain.com/api/user-login
  https://appdomain.com/login
  https://appdomain.com/Check-login
  https://appdomain.com/user-login
```

but each of these urls return a 404 error.

5. Laravel - version 5.5.50
6. part of api.php

   ```
   Route::group(['prefix' => 'v1'], function () {
      Route::post('/user-login',['as' => 'login','uses' => 
     'api\v1\UserController@user_login']);
   });
   ```

**7. when I added file public_htm/index.php - any request to api returns that file**

Which url is correct?
What else can I check?
How can this be fixed?

Any advice - I will be very grateful.

Comment: for api routes, put them inside `routes/api.php` and automatically a prefix `/api/` will be added to all of your api routes, such as  named "login" is callable as `/api/login`

Comment: I added part api.php in my question

Comment: Based on api.php , login route should be `/api/v1/user-login` , use method post. Did you try to access this route ? Because screenshot from `artisan route:list` state otherwise `login web` with different controller instead of `App\Http\Controllers\api\v1\UserController`

Comment: yet - user-login. I fixed it in the question(image) - but the request returns a 404

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Method 1:**

Change Document Root to `public_html/public` and upload the source code to `public_html`.

**Method 2:**

Upload the source code except `public` folder to the parent folder of `public_html` folder. And upload the files in `public` folder to `public_html` folder.

Add the following code to `public_html/index.php`:

```
$app->bind('path.public', function() {
    return __DIR__;
});
```

Comment: Came to say this is the answer.

Comment: thanks, I didn't understand your answer at first. i copied public/index.php to public_html -  it works

Comment: @FetFrumos `app`, `routes`,  `bootstrap`, `.env`... etc should be under **parent folder** of `public_html` folder. Otherwise, it would be a security concern. For example: if `.env` is under `public_html` folder, anyone can access it via http request.

Comment: Editing index file is not proper way.

Answer (score 1):

Place .htaccess file into root directory of your project . public_html/.htaccess

Comment: this file is already there, see point 2

Comment: some how your mod_rewrite extension is not working . did you verify if is it installed ? Re write module ?

Comment: Does you web routes are working ?

Comment: I will check mod_rewrite - thank you

Comment: Web routers - not working

Comment: what it says when you hit any web route ?

Comment: I get error - 404 Not Found

Comment: check your apache .

Comment: exactly what apache settings should I check?

Comment: add a dummy index.php (just with simple html) file in your root dir.. to check apache is Ok !

Comment: when I added file public_htm/index.php - any request to api returns that file

Comment: You said you did not have prior experience with laravel . you have to take bunch of diff. steps to make your app working on Cpanel. it's not just upload your zip to root or just .htaccess

Comment: Still same issue ? 404 ?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you should do is to verify if your request actually hits your Laravel Application. There are number of ways you can do this, like adding additional testing routes in `web.php` or `api.php`

Addtionally, you may install [clockwork](https://github.com/itsgoingd/clockwork) and capture all the request, so you can also easily see if your request actually hits the laravel app.

If it hits your Laravel application, turn on the debug mode in your `env` file and put the application in development mode, then try checking the laravel logs for any error.

If your request is not hitting the laravel application, then its something related to your server configuration or laravel installation configuration.

Normally, the root folder for laravel application is in `laravel-root-directory/public/` which should be the root folder when configuring the domain, but I've seen people where they move the root folder to actual laravel app root and not inside `public` folder